# DataTable и обновление данных

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, .net

Здравствуйте. Как обновить DataTable после поиска в таблице?
Названия типа FbDataAdapter и DataTable пишу без названия переменной, чтобы было понятней.
Например, был запрос в начале загрузки

```
 SELECT * FROM "ТАБЛИЦА"
```

Данные отображаются корректно (с использованием FbDataAdapter.Fill)
Но когда я выполняю поиск с запросом FbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText, например

```
FbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM \"ТАБЛИЦА\" WHERE \"Код\" LIKE '%123%'";
```

а затем,

```
 FbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 FbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
```

То выборка получается, но старые данные никуда не деваются, т.е. эта выборка добавляется к ним, например, 2 записи. Пробовал перед выборкой:

```
 DataTable.Clear();
```

Очищается DataTable, но после выборки выводится только одна запись, хотя через тот же IBExpert по тому же запросу выводится, например, 2 записи.

Как правильно реализовать это, чтобы после второго запроса корректно обновлялась DataTable? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась.
Сначала присваиваем компоненту

```
  DataGridView.DataSource = null;
```

Затем после операций с DataTable снова присваиваем DataGridView.DataSource изменённый DataTable.